# Is there an rtmp (protocol) URL anywhere on the internet I can test?

Tags: rtmp, sample

I'm building a video player in flash based on NetStream, and all I need to test it is a functioning RTMP url, but I cannot find a single one on the entire internet through google.

Is anyone aware of any valid sample rtmp streams and their URLs that I can use to test this thing?

Comment: in case you are still looking: rtmp://62.113.210.250/medienasa-live/rbw_high and rtmp://62.113.210.250/medienasa-live/ok-merseburg_high are still live

Comment: @Hibbem Not any more !

Answer (score 9):

JWPLayer has a demo page: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29395/rtmp-single-stream/

You can open the page, view the source and copy and paste the `rtmp://` URL from there.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I use a Wowza sample page availabe at https://web.duke.edu/dms/flashtest/ (Link broken)

Comment: Another page with different streams: http://www.hdwplayer.com/rtmp-streaming-video-player/

Answer (score -4):

For the ones who look at this question later and want a quick answer, attaching this url which I got from koenpeters's answer

```
rtmp://fms.12E5.edgecastcdn.net/0012E5/mp4:videos/8Juv1MVa-485.mp4
```

Answer (score -6):

I do not know still are you need to answer. You can use curl for that purpose, just do this.

```
curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail your_rtmp_link
```

above command is working on linux. If you do not have curl just install by the following command,

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Also I did this by c++. I used curl c++ library and checking my rtmp link each 3 minute.