# ONVIF / RTSP / RTMP protocol URLs in the web

Tags: url, video, rtsp, rtmp, onvif

Is there any this (look above) certain types URLs in the Internet? I need this urls for testing purpose.

I've found couple working RTSP urls:

- rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov
- rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov

Also I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576840/is-there-an-rtmp-protocol-url-anywhere-on-the-internet-i-can-test) topic, but it doesn't have working links for now, at least I haven't found.

Does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use Spydroid application which will record from your mobile camera and provides RTSP livestream.

You can use RTSP url provided by Spydroid to stream on your application.

Here is the link 
https://github.com/fyhertz/spydroid-ipcamera

Comment: Unfortunately, the app does not work for me :(
I can't start streaming when I'm opening browser and trying to connect to camera

Comment: There are application using them you can turn your computer into onvif server

Answer (score 1):

I had exact same problem searching for live rtmp streams, unfortunately someone closed first popular question found by google that you mentioned, hope this topic will live.
Urls I was able to find:

```
//cartoon
rtmp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov

//car ad
rtmp://s3b78u0kbtx79q.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/honda_accord
```